# Find image under $T$ of the line $x_1 + 2x_2 = 3$ -- Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

We are asked to find the image under $T$ of the line $$x_1 + 2x_2 = 3$$.

Consider the linear operator $T:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ with standard matrix $$ A = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{array}\right]
$$

The line $x_1 + 2x_2 = 3$ contains the points $$(-1,2), (1,1), (3,0)$$

I do not understand how they arrive at the aforementioned points.

Comment: what is T??????

Comment: What is your definition for $T$?It seems it is an homework problem.Note that every $ 2\times 2$ matrix is a possible choice for your $T$.

Comment: Still what is $T$? There infinitely many such operators.

Comment: parametric equation of the line is $x_1 = -1 + 2t, x_2 = 2-t$ where $t$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not understand how they arrive at the aforementioned points.

Make $x_1 = -1$. Solve for $x_2$ and get $x_2 = 2$. So $(-1,2)$ is in the line.

Make $x_1 =1$. Solve for $x_2$ and get $x_2 = 1$. So $(1,1)$ is in the line.

Make $x_1 = 3$. Solve for $x_2$ and get $x_2 = 0$. So $(3,0)$ is in the line.

<strike>We can't help you further since we don't know that $T$ is.</strike> Now we know. You can write: $$[T(x_1,x_2)] = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1+x_2 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}$$Since $T$ is invertible, $T$ will take that line to another line. And you only need two points, instead of three. Compute $T(-1,2)$, $T(1,1)$, and the line passing through these points. Now it's on you!

Comment: Any rhyme or reason why I need to 'make' $x_1$ equal to $-1$?

Comment: You want to find points on the line. For $x_1 = -1$, there is only one point $(-1,x_2)$ on the line, since it is not vertical. The way to find this correspondent $x_2$ is plugging $x_1 = -1$ and solving for $x_2$.

Comment: So what if I choose a different arbitrary constant for $x_1$ say, 3. Then $x_2=0$

Comment: You'll have another point $(3, y)$ in the line. Then you can solve for $y$ (which, by the way, will be $0$, see above)

Answer (score 2):

you can parametrise the line by $$(x_1, x_2)^\top =(-1,2)^\top  + t(2, -1)^\top. $$ the point $(-1,2)^\top$ is mapped by $T$ to $-1(1,0)^\top+2(1,1)^\top = (1, 2)^\top$ and $(2,-1)^\top$ is mapped by $T$ to $2(1,0)^\top -(1,1)^\top = (1, -1)^\top$

therefore $$A(x_1,x_2)^\top =(1,2)^\top+t(1,-1)^\top. \tag 1  $$

$(1)$  represents the line $$x_1 + x_2 = 3. $$